# LAB: Sorting TV Shows (dictionaries and lists), Removing Zero in front of Season

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a different code than the previous user requested, but I have the same problem.  I've tried repeatedly and cannot seem to remove the zero before the seasons:

```
07: Rules of Engagement; Medium; Lux Video Theatre
08: Mama; Barney Miller; Castle
10: Will & Grace; Smallville; Modern Family; Friends
11: Cheers; The Jeffersons
12: Murder, She Wrote; NYPD Blue
14: Dallas; Bonanza
15: ER
20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order; Law & Order: Special Victims Unit
30: The Simpsons
```

expected output

```
7: Rules of Engagement; Medium; Lux Video Theatre
8: Mama; Barney Miller; Castle
10: Will & Grace; Smallville; Modern Family; Friends
11: Cheers; The Jeffersons
12: Murder, She Wrote; NYPD Blue
14: Dallas; Bonanza
15: ER
20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order; Law & Order: Special Victims Unit
30: The Simpsons
```

---

CODE:

```
#  Trial 47...
file_name = input()              # remove typed text later 'enter file name: '
user_file = open(file_name)
input_list = user_file.readlines()
#  print(input_list)                                # remove print statement

my_diction = {}

for index in range (len(input_list)):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        diction_key = input_list[index].strip('\n')
        if diction_key not in my_diction:
            my_diction[diction_key] = []
    else:
        my_diction[diction_key].append(input_list[index].strip('\n'))

#  print(my_diction)                           # remove print statement

#  print(sorted(my_diction.keys()))            # remove print statement
sorted_keys = sorted(my_diction.keys())
output_file = ''
tv_show_list = []

for d_key in sorted_keys:
    output_file += d_key + ': '
    for tvshow in my_diction[d_key]:
        output_file += tvshow + '; '
        tv_show_list.append(tvshow)
    output_file = output_file[:-2] + '\n'
print(output_file)
file = open("output_keys.txt", "w")
file.write(output_file)
file.close()


tv_show_list.sort()
#  print(tv_show_list)                             # remove print statement
sorted_list = ''
for tv_show in tv_show_list:
    sorted_list += tv_show + '\n'
print(sorted_list)
file = open("output_titles.txt", "w")
file.write(sorted_list)
file.close()
```

---

Comment: What part of this code is expected to "remove the zero before the seasons"?

Comment: I've added: output_file = output_file.lstrip('0') before the print(output_file) and it gets rid of only the zero in front of the 7, not the 8, nor the 9 in further testing....

Comment: Scott Hunter: After the keys are sorted, I need the key to be stripped of the leading zero...

Comment: GOT IT:     output_file += d_key.lstrip('0') + ': '        Thanks Scott Hunter, you made me think a bit more!